# NSPropertyListSerialization returns nil when trying to convert NSDictionary to NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata

I'm trying to convert an NSDictionary to NSData to store in core data, but I am getting a nil value returned to me.  error states 'Unknown format option' after the call.

```
NSString *error = nil;
NSData *d = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:data format:NSPropertyListImmutable errorDescription:&error];
```

The data I'm trying to convert is an NSDictionary with NSStrings as keys and values.  Here is a dump of the data dictionary:

```
Printing description of data:
<CFBasicHash 0xc96fd60 [0x18ecb38]>{type = immutable dict, count = 4,
entries =>
0 : <CFString 0x17c9fc [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "title"} = <CFString 0xecc8040 [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "test"}
1 : <CFString 0x17ca2c [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "author"} = <CFString 0xc9643f0 [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "test"}
2 : <CFString 0x17ca0c [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "goal"} = <CFString 0xc96f730 [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "test"}
4 : <CFString 0x17ca1c [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "description"} = <CFString 0xc9643f0 [0x18ecb38]>{contents = "test"}
}
Printing description of error:
Unknown format option
```

Any ideas on where I went wrong or alternate ways to convert an NSDictionary to NSData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation says, the `format` parameter must be one of these:

```
NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat
NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0
NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
```